# What is the best strategy to traverse the thumbnails in a modal window (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I’m creating a typical photo gallery for my website. Something simple: one page to show the thumbnails and one page to display the photo with the photo details, comments, etc...

But, I want to give an option to the user to traverse the thumbnails by using a modal window without having to click the thumbnail to view the photo, then go back, click another thumbnail to view the next photo and so. Some sort of a photo preview, a quick view.

My question is not how to go about, I will do my research and figure it out, and ask questions in this community. My question is more about the strategy to use for traversing the thumbnails.

The thumbs are display on my page using a typical ul list, like so

```
<ul>
<li><a href=""><img src="" width="" height="" title="" alt=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" width="" height="" title="" alt=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" width="" height="" title="" alt=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" width="" height="" title="" alt=""></a></li>
...
</ul>
```

I will use jquery to display the images on a modal window, with a short caption (probably the title of the tag). And I will have next and prev buttons to traverse the photos, and a close button to shutdown the modal window. Something simple.

My question is what is the best strategy to traverse the thumbnails? Should I use the ul list in place and traverse the photos or should I assign all of the photos info in an array (using jquery) and use that array to traverse the photos?

What is the standard out there, the best method? I will then figure out how to go from there, but I absolutely need to have a good foundation before proceeding.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each image a class (`thumbnail`?)

Now you can easily grab the collection, e.g.

```
$(".thumbnail").each(function() {
   // do whatever
});
```

Keep additional info in attributes:

```
<img class="thumbnail" data-caption="Front View" data-id="123" ... />
```

A list styled to display horizontally without bullets is fine and pretty typical.

Comment: ok, thanks. so if i understand well, your strategy is to grab the collection and store it in an array

Comment: If that's the approach you think easiest. You can also leave it in the DOM and query it as needed.